# FPDF not outputting lines

Tags: php, line, cell, fpdf

I have FPDF document I am creating running into an issue with it not outputting all the cells I created. Will output up until the Print Name: line with the underlined cell.

Then will not output next lines I have multiple lines all with same parameters as Print Name: line like Dimensions: none of them print. Not sure as to why. Any help appreciated.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',12);
$pdf->Cell(189 ,5,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(189 ,5,'Your plate charges follow:',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(189 ,3,'',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(10 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(39 ,5,'Print Name:',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(140 ,5,'','B',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(10 ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(39 ,5,'Dimensions:',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(140 ,5,'','B',0,1);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include enough code for us to be able to try and reproduce the problem. The snippet you supplied is not enough to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6th parameter on this line `$pdf->Cell(140 ,5,'','B',0,1);` is not valid. The allowed values are

- L or empty string: left align (default value)
- C: center
- R: right align

Change the 1 to one of the values shown above. Same thing for the last line in your question `$pdf->Cell(140 ,5,'','B',0,1);`.

Comment: Thank you Dave that fixed my issue